# Anchor tag quit working after several months and was not changed

Tags: html, http, anchor

I created a list of FAQs with anchor tags. They have been working for several months. The other day I went to check everything and they weren't working. They began redirecting me to my homepage instead. I was using a name so I changed it to h3 id and still can't get it to work. What is the deal?

```
<h2>
    Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
<p>
    <strong><a href="#Question3">sample question?</a></strong></p>
<p>


<h2>Answers</h2>
<p>
    <h3 id="Question3">sample question?</h3></p>
```

This is where I get redirected (our homepage):

> `http://www.newhorizonsinc.com/index.php#Question3`

Answer (score 1):

Your FAQ page has `<base href="http://www.newhorizonsinc.com/index.php" />` in the head.

All links will be relative to there instead of `http://www.newhorizonsinc.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=78:foster-faqs&catid=2:new-horizons`

Comment: okay. How is that changed?

Comment: I'd take the `<base>` element out entirely. It usually does more harm than good.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help. Don't understand why they 'closed my question' saying it was 'not a real question'